# Bound on how many 2-colored graphs have maxredclique $i$, maxblueclique $j$

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Fix $i,j$. I want a bound $F(i,j)$ on the following:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ (the number of 2-colorings of the edges of $K_n$ such that
                                the MAX RED clique is size exactly $i$ (that's an $i$ not a 1)
                                and the MAX BLUE clique is of size exactly $j$.

Caveats:

1)  If $n=3$ then  coloring (1,2) RED, (2,3) RED, (1,3) BLUE
is counted
DIFF from coloring (2,3) RED, (3,1) RED, (1,2) BLUE.

2) The sum does not really go to infinity since when
$n\ge$  RAMSEY$(i+1,j+1)$ it will be 0.

3) It might be that having MAX RED CLIQUE $\le i$ and
MAX BLUE CLIQUE $\le j$
doesn't change things much and is easier to compute.

Comment: I took the liberty of LaTeX'ing your posting.

Comment: I found some introductory material. There are a few people on MO who do combinatorics, anyway

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory 

http://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/ChRam.pdf 

Comment: I also found this other stuff, as i am trying to figure out whether the OP was getting a bachelor's degree in mathematics at Stony Brook at the same time I was, late 1970's...http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/ramsey/ramsey.html